# Unity: PlayOneShot stopped when Stop is called

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-source

I have a method that plays a clip as a one shot:

```
public void PlaySingleFull(AudioClip clip) {
    efxSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
}
```

I also have a method that stops anything playing from the same source:

```
public void StopEfx() {
    efxSource.Stop();
}
```

PlayOneShot() is supposed to ignore any calls from Stop() and play anyway but mine does stop when Stop() is called. Does anyone have any idea what's up?

Comment: Add all the code, there may be side effects we can't see with just those two methods you are showing

Answer (score 0):

You don't really let us see any execution code, but I am guessing the problem is that you put StopEfx() after the PlaySingleFull(). This will cancel the new effect/song immediately after it's queued. It's the only thing I can think of right now, but I need more code to be sure...